# Using jQuery, how can I create a select list using a page's H4 titles as options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I would like to take all of the H2, H3, or H4 titles on a page and use them to create a `<select>` box where every option is a page title. This should include the value. I want to eventually use the select box to trigger events; every time someone chooses a title the corresponding pargraph after each title will `fadeIn()` and any visible paragraphs will`fadeOut()`.

For example, imagine the page looks like this:

```
<select></select>

<h4>Some title 1</h4>
<p>Paragraph that followstitle 1</p>

<h4>Some title 2</h4>
<p>Paragraph that followstitle 2</p>
```

Turns into:

```
<select>
    <option value="Some title 1">Some title 1</option>
    <option value="Some title 2">Some title 2</option>
</select>

<h4>Some title 1</h4>
<p>Paragraph that followstitle 1</p>

<h4>Some title 2</h4>
<p>Paragraph that followstitle 2</p>
```

I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and cannot change this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through each h4 tag and create an option for each one:

```
$('h4').each(function() {
  $('select').append('<option value="' + $(this).text() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelector` produces a list of elements matching a CSS selector. We'll first use that to locate the `<select>` element we're adding `<option>`s to, then use `.querySelectorAll()` to find all of the titles we're adding options for. After we create each `<option>` we copy over the `.textContent` property from the original heading.

```js
var selector = document.querySelector('select');

var titles = document.querySelectorAll('h2, h3, h4');
for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    var titleOption = document.createElement('option');
    titleOption.textContent = titles[i].textContent;
    titleOption.value = titles[i].id;

    selector.appendChild(titleOption);
}
```

The `value` property of each `<option>` is set to the ID of the heading element the title is from. As long as your headings all have IDs, this lets you easily jump to them when they're selected:

```python
selector.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.location.hash = selector.value;
});
```

Try it out [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremy/g2cc2/).

Answer (score 0):

This adds the options, building them with jQuery and not strings, and attaches a change event handler that will fadeOut any visible paragraphs that comes after a H4 tag, except the one mathing the value choosen in the select, which will be faded in :

```
$('select').append(function() {
    return $.map($('h4'), function(h4) { return $('<option />', {text: $(h4).text()}) });
}).change(function() {
    var p = $('h4:contains('+this.value+')').next('p');
    $('h4 + p').not(p).fadeOut();
    p.fadeIn();
}).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3VN2/1/)

Comment: Looks interesting, but I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'", which I imagine is due to the version of jQuery I am using not having `on`. I am using jQuery 1.4.2, though not by choice. Unfortunately, I cannot change this.

Comment: @user2566414 - I've edited out on(), but you really should upgrade, as 1.4 was quite a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

This comes a little close...

```
<select id="myselect"></select>

<h4 class="clazz" id="h41">Some title 1</h4>
<p>Paragraph that followstitle 1</p>

<h4 class="clazz" id="h42">Some title 2</h4>
<p>Paragraph that followstitle 2</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var select = document.getElementById("myselect");

$("H4").each(function(){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = $(this).text();
    option.value = this.id;
    select.appendChild(option);
});

$(select).on("change", function(){
    $("H4.clazz").next("p").fadeOut();
    $("H4.clazz").fadeOut();
    var id = this.value;
    $("#" + id).next("p").fadeIn();
    $("#" + id).fadeIn();
}).change();
});
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ikhanm/mZ8Zt/)

The rest of it is upto you to make it look good.